# Google API to get all zip codes reachable withing specified time from a point

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was seaching for the google api for solving my distance related problem. I found many types of API that can give me the time between two zip codes. But my requirement is following:

I want to find out all the zip codes those are reachable within a time [for example 1 hour] from perticuler zip code.

I didn't found such api available. Is there any available ?

We can get the time between two zip codes like - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=95050&destinations=94087.
But this approch will cost in many more api calls.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen time as an option (great thought though). You may have better luck with distance. Although, I might be wrong, check out this:

[The Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=en)

It seems to include distance and duration between two points.

Comment: I understand that this is a partial answer. I'm still looking for a list of zip codes within a radius.

Comment: If the requirement is to find the zips located with in radius [in terms of distance], there is one api available [not google api] - http://www.zipcodeapi.com/API#radius. My requirement here is for getting teh zips reachable within specified time.

Comment: Aha. My only thought at this time is to use the API you mentioned to get zip codes within a radius of "max time", a reasonable but rough distance (miles for example) to start the next step (glad you found that, I was searching). Then, run Google Maps Distance Matrix API from the center point to each location to get time, running some extra math on your end to knock out the ones that are too long away. My concern with that is hitting a ceiling of max requests. Let me know if that helps release some ideas or if you would like a code example.